# Chrome and Firefox does refresh all js file except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I'm running an application on jBoss.

In one page there are many js files. Chrome and Firefox see the changes on all js file when I reload the page, except one.

I open Chrome (firefox) in unknown mode, disabled the cache of Chrome console (Firefox console), reload the page, clean and restart the application server and rebuild the application.

Nothing.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: have you tried ctrl+f5? :)

Comment: Is the script being linked to an older version and you renamed / moved the new one you're looking to use? Can you try navigating to the page in another browser that you haven't used before (like IE or Edge)?

Comment: I don't know how do you call your .js but try somthink like this `<script src="somejs.js?v=1"></script>`

Comment: its better to check if you are really using a proper file from the specific folder not from the other one which is dynamically created when you build your application. sometime back when we worked with maven we faced similar issue instead of file from css folder the devs were using file from target/css folder.

Comment: @nowhere, Yep. But nothing, again.

Comment: @QBernard, it's incredible. I renamed the file from messages.js to messagess.js and Chrome gets me and 404. Right. I rename the file like before, in messages.js and Chrome load old version, outdated of this file.

Comment: @Jai, How can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

When linking the scripts on you pages you can put something after the file like

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="<file_name.js>?yyyymmdd"></script>.
```

This "yyyymmdd" can be the current Date/datetime (never caches) or the last modification date of the js file you are including (it cancel the cache only when you modify the script).

That is the approach we use.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, go to developer tools(press F12), go to Network panel, there check 'Disable cache' option and load your page..